# Simplest way to automatically send data from users computer to rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm writing a simple app that keeps track of how many lines of code there are in my rails application. It will keep track of how many lines of code I write per hour. At the moment I'm using a crontab command that runs every 10 minutes and appends the number of lines to a file.

`0,10,20,30,40,50 * * * * cd bimble ; find . \( -name '*.rb' -o -name '*.erb' \) | xargs wc -l | tail -1 | sed 's/total//' >>linesOfCode.txt`

Rather than writing to a file I would like to send numberOfLines variable to a rails app, what would be the easiest simplest way to do this?

Do I have to write an api? something like this http://squarism.com/2011/04/01/how-to-write-a-ruby-rails-3-rest-api/ or is there a better way to do this?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Full API sounds like overkill. You can have a controller action that responds to GET, and pulls the right value you want out of the params hash, and does whatever you want internally in rails with it. Something like:

```
def getline
  lines = params[:lines]
  # do whatever, put in model, etc with lines var
end
```

Then you can simply have your cron script send that via a wget similar to

```
wget http://rails_url/controller/getline?lines=`cat linesOfCode.txt` &> /dev/null
```